# Formating .bst specific with burlalt

Tags: bibtex, formatting, arxiv

I obtained a bst file from [here](https://www.math.cmu.edu/%7Egautam/sj/blog/20171114-bibtex-doi.html), which is great. But I need bibtex to show the arXiv as follows:

[image]

So far I have managed to get:

[image]

The code in the bst file that I have "edited" is:

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
    { "" }
    { "\burlalt{" archivePrefix * eprint * primaryClass * "}
    {http://arxiv.org/abs/" * eprint * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

but can't find a way to insert the colon : and the square brackets []. This is my first time working directly with bst files, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I did it! Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546396/bib-style-format-for-bibtext-bst-file-explained-by-an-example) amazing post which explains a little bit how bst formatting works and manage to solve the problem.

```
FUNCTION {format.eprint}
{ eprint empty$
     { "" }
     { "\burlalt{" " [" * archivePrefix * " " * eprint * " [" * primaryClass * "]" * "]" * "}{http://arxiv.org/abs/" * eprint * "}" * }
  if$
}
```

So to insert any character you must use quote-unquote and proceed to concatenate the next element with: *, and that's it.

Cheers!

EDIT: I'm sure there must be another fancier way of doing it, let me know if there is some!